# Using Celery for cron jobs time based on users time decision

Tags: django, cron, celery

I have project in which the user decides for how long a Post will be active, so after certain time the post will change the state.

To solve this, as for running async tasks and for performance, I think the best choice is to use Celery.

I haven't use Celery yet, I've only read the documentation about ETA (estimated time of arrival) and Expiration, right [here.](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown)

My questions are:

what is the proper way (if it's possible) to do this?

Is it recommended to use a Duration field or a Datetime field on the model (maximum duration is 1 day and 12 hours)?

Do I need to create a cron job for each Post or Celery can can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Celery` for this, and there are ways to hook in a database update to a Celery scheduled task, but it may be overkill for such a simple situation as showing or not showing expired posts.

Here is a simple example of setting a calculated property.  Just reference the calculate property `active` to decide whether to show the Post or not.

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now, localtime

class Post(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    expires = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)

    @property
    def active(self):
        return self.expires > localtime(now())

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.created = localtime(now())
        self.expires = self.created + datetime.timedelta(hours=36)
        return super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think this doesn't work as when creating the post it executes `self.expires` and `self.created` returns a `NoneType`.

Comment: @Rod, I edited my answer to explicitly set `self.created`. The issue may have been that Django doesn't set that value until `save` is called. Try again . This should work.

Comment: This works but it doesn't solve the problem as I need to call the `active` function for each post to see if it has expired. The idea is that the Post changes state automatically.

Comment: @Rod, the post would change state automatically based upon the time. `active` changes to `False`.  You could also use cron to do batch processing, it's just a lot more configuration, where solution may work, but yes, depends on the final use case.

Comment: I had no idea. But is it possible I can use that value to update a model field? Like another property that if `active` is `False` it updates the `self.state`. I'm asking because it didn't work and this is the final step to solve my doubt.

Comment: @Rod, for cron, you would add a task to your `crontab` to call a "custom django management command".  In your custom command, call any `state` update, etc.. that you want. Here is the link for custom commands: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/